# Why does my code change the innertext back to the starting value?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

This is quite a simple problem that is somehow eluding me, and my google fu is also letting me down. What I expect to happen is that the  changes value and stays there. But for some reason after the function is called it returns back up to the
`let button = document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener("click", ChangeText);`
line. And it just overwrites what I just did.

I am fully aware that I could use onclick on the button but we're meant to use eventlisteners for this.

Here is the html and js. and a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/bgd2n381/

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener("click", ChangeText);


function ChangeText() {
  let label = document.querySelector('#text');
  if (label.innerText == "Start Text") {
    label.innerText = "Text has been changed";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="js/uppgift2.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label id="text">Start Text</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your button submits the form, and the page is reloaded.

Comment: Ahh.. Boy do i look foolish now. Is there a way for it to not reload?

Comment: Just read the top answer in the post mplungjan has linked.

Comment: Same question twice in one hour :)

Comment: Haha thank you all for the help, i got it working now!

Comment: One additional thing: Your script is defined BEFORE the form exists. EITHER move the script to after the form (for example before the `</body>` tag) OR wrap in `window.addEventListener("load",function() { /* your other eventlistener assignment */ })` - the reason it works in the fiddle is that the fiddle adds this step for you

Comment: PS: I made you a snippet. It is the button in the editor that looks like `[<>]`